# How close to death is my hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I ran Crystal Disk Info to look at the SMART information on my external 2 TB drive and it's reporting a "Caution" health status. The specific error is the Current Pending Sector Count, which is 196. I have tried power cycling the drive, and it didn't get fixed. Should I be worried yet? Is this a situation where I should immediately buy another hard drive and back everything up or is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Regardless of how close your hard drive is to death -- yes, you should back up everything.

Comment: I agree, and in fact this drive is primarily used for backups of other things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from [SecurityNow!](http://www.grc.com/securitynow.htm) podcast number 81:

> STEVE: The problem is, and in fact the reason that we’ve always used the slogan “SMART is dumb” at GRC, is we see dead drives all the time where the SMART system says, oh, everything’s fine.
>
> LEO:  It’s all working, no problem.
>
> STEVE:  Exactly.  The drive can die spontaneously while SMART is completely happy and sees nothing going wrong.  At the same time there are drives which look like they’re on their last throes from a standpoint of the SMART data that just keep on going for years.

Long story short, you cannot rely on SMART data in any meaningful way. If you want to play it safe, back up your data, if you want to be really safe, back up and get a new drive.

Comment: Some (most?) manufacturers will replace (under warranty) drives with SMART errors.  If the drive isn't out of warranty, it would be worthwhile to explore that option.

Comment: I checked, and it is indeed under warranty, so that's exactly what I'm going to do.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see [here](http://www.ariolic.com/activesmart/smart-attributes/current-pending-sector-count.html), a warning in Current Pending Sector Count indicates potential bad sections.

For those high density disks, a bad sector can spread really soon, so you should start backing up now.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes):

> Current Pending Sector Count
>   Count of "unstable" sectors
>   (waiting to be remapped, because of read errors).
>
> If an unstable
>   sector is subsequently read successfully, this value is decreased and
>   the sector is not remapped. Read errors on a sector will not remap the
>   sector (since it might be readable later); instead, the drive firmware
>   remembers that the sector needs to be remapped, and remaps it the next
>   time it's written.

Basically the drive has detected that sectors could not be read and as such has been marked as potentially unsafe with the intention of either retrying the read at some later point (and putting it back into use if it succeeds) or remapping it with one of the store of reserved spare sectors the next time it is written to.

That high a number does not look like a good thing to me, it could be a sign of the drive failing. As mentioned SMART is not necessarily a reliable indicator of drive health though some indication that it may be failing is better than none.